# Finding smallest set of criteria for uniqueness

Tags: algorithm, set, unique

I have a collection of objects with properties. I want to find the simplest set of criteria that will specify exactly one of these objects (I do not care which one).

For example, given {a=1, b=1, c=1}, {a=1, b=2, c=1}, {a=1, b=1, c=2}, specifying b==2 (or c==2) will give me an unique object.

Likewise, given {a=1, b=1, c=1}, {a=1, b=2, c=2}, {a=1, b=2, c=1}, specifying b==2 and c==2 (or b==1 && c==1 or b==2 && c==1) will give me an unique object.

This sounds like a known problem, with a known solution, but I haven't been able to find the correct formulation of the problem to allow me to Google it.

Comment: So given an object, do you want to find the smallest set of criteria which will separate it from the set? I.e. given {a=1, b=1, c=1}, {a=1, b=2, c=1}, {a=1, b=1, c=2}, and the object {a=1, b=2, c=1}, the solution would be b==2?

Comment: @Jacob: No, given a set, I want the smallest set of criteria, that will separate *any* object from the set.

Comment: What do you mean by "any"? Do you mean you need a different set of criteria for each object?

Comment: @Jacob: No, I want the smallest set of criteria, that will select a single object. Given {a=1}, {a=1}, {a=2}, I want a==2. Given {a=1, b=2, c=1, d=1}, {a=1, b=1, c=2, d=1}, {a=1, b=1, c=1, d=2}, {a=1, b=2, c=2, d=1}, {a=1, b=2, c=1, d=2}, {a=1, b=1, c=2, d=2}, {a=2, b=1, c=1, d=1}, I also want a==2.

Comment: So the smallest set of criteria which results in one object (you don't care which)?

Comment: @Jacob: Yes. I will try to edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: OK, one more question: are inequalities allowed?

Comment: @Jacob: I cannot think of any examples where inequalities would make for a smaller set of criteria than equalities. Am I overlooking anything?

Comment: This is a really interesting problem. Last question (probably): what's the domain of the input (integers, reals,etc.)?

Comment: @Jacob: In my actual problem it is strings. But again, I don't really think it makes any difference (at least as long as the collection of objects is finite).

Comment: Well, it matters because if cast as an optimization problem, it makes it an integer program.

Comment: @Jacob: As long as there is a finite collection of objects (with a finite number of properties), no matter which domain we choose the problem should be isomorphic to the equivalent problem with integers (since there must be a finite number of different values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The freedom of choosing the target is sort of unusual. If the target is specified, then this is essentially the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). Here's two corresponding instances side by side.

```
A={1,2,3} B={2,4} C={3,4} D={4,5}

0: {a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0}  # separate 0 from the others
1: {a=1, b=0, c=0, d=0}
2: {a=1, b=1, c=0, d=0}
3: {a=1, b=0, c=1, d=0}
4: {a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1}
5: {a=0, b=0, c=0, d=1}
```

While set cover is NP-hard, however, your problem has an O(m<sup>log n + O(1)</sup> poly(n)) algorithm where m is the number of attributes and n is the number of items (the optimal set of criteria has size at most log n), which makes it rather unlikely that an NP-hardness proof is forthcoming. I'm reminded of the situation with the [Junta problem](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/the-junta-problem/) (basically the theoretical formulation of feature selection).

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a known problem in AI - feature selection. There are many algorithms for doing this Just Google "feature selection" "artificial intelligence".

The main issue is that when the samples set is large, you need to use some sort of heuristics in order to reach a solution within a reasonable time.

---

[Feature Selection in Data Mining](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22feature%20selection%22&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://dollar.biz.uiowa.edu/~street/research/dmoc.pdf&ei=9J_cTpilGOih4gS_odT6DQ&usg=AFQjCNGKUcYgPG3vwSiCZsK5HM_cvnPxUw&sig2=3RKh8kNy7lUOm30PbIwhBg)

> The main idea of feature selection is to choose a subset of input
>   variables by eliminating features with little or no predictive
>   information.

Comment: +1 I hope you don't mind I took the liberty of including some explanation about feature selection into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how easily this could be translated into an algoritm but using SQL, which is already set based, it could go like this

- construct a table with all possible combinations of columns from the input table
- select all combinations that appear equal to the amount of records present in the input table as distinct combinations.

#### SQL Script

```
;WITH q (a, b, c) AS (
  SELECT '1', '1', '1'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1', '2', '2'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1', '2', '1'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1', '1', '2'
)
SELECT  col
FROM    (
          SELECT val = a, col = 'a'  FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT b, 'b' FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT c, 'c' FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT a+b, 'a+b' FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT a+c, 'a+c' FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT b+c, 'b+c' FROM q
          UNION ALL SELECT a+b+c, 'a+b+c' FROM q
        ) f
GROUP BY
        col        
HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT (val)) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be defined as follows:

```
1 1 1 -> A
1 2 1 -> B
1 1 2 -> C
.
.
```

where `1 1 1` is called the feature vector and `A` is the object class. You can then use [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) (with pruning) to find a set of rules to classify objects. So, if your objective is to automatically decide the set of criteria to identify object `A` then, you can observe the path on the decision tree which leads to `A`.

If you have access to [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/classregtree.html), it is really easy to obtain a decision tree for your data.